# android:send dynamic image through mail

Tags: android, image, email, dynamic

Hi i am making an app in which i am **dynamically** getting the image from server and i want to give user the option to **mail** that image. I am using following code but i dont how to set path of image in below code.

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,getResources().getString(R.string.emlSendToFriendSubject));
  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{emailto});
  emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,getResources().getString(R.string.emlSendToFriendBody));
  File file = getFileStreamPath(EMAIL_TEMP_FILE);
 emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file://"+file.getAbsolutePath()));
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,getResources().getString(R.string.btnSendToFriend)),ActMain.EMAIL_DONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the path to the image in this line:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file://"+file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

, where `file` is the image you want to send.

Also, note that the second call to `setType` will override the effects of the first call you made.

Comment: Can you please elobrate about settype and i just have to write the image url in file?